# Populate firestore database with json data from firebase real time database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a flutter project and I need to populate my firestore database with some JSON data.

However, I realized I can upload the data to firebase real time database but cannot transfer it to firestore .
I don't want the data on the real time database but on the firestore

I want move this firestore
[image]

into this firestore database
[image]

**

> If anyone knows how to I can populate my firestore database with my
> JSON data, I'd be really glad.

**Thanks in advance**

**

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to transfer data from Cloud Firestore to the Realtime Database, as both databases have a completely different data model.

If you want to transfer the data automatically, you'll have to write a script that:

1. Reads the data from [Realtime Database](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/overview) through its API.
2. Converts the JSON structure to a bunch of documents.
3. Writes the data to [Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview) through its API.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. as @Frank Van Puffelen mentioned, there is no direct way to do it.
However, I found that if I want to transfer from firestore to real-time database, I will need to first export the real-time database as JSON and then use a programming language e.g. js, python, Go, etc. to update the local JSON on my firestore.

follow these rules

1. Export the real-time database data to JSON onto your desktop
2. Return to your firestore project and navigate to the project settings on the right top corner, on the service account tab.
3. choose the language you wanna use to communicate with your database I used python
4. select on generate a private key to download it. create a folder and put it there.
5. copy the code generated for you:

   import firebase_admin

> ```
> from firebase_admin import credentials
> from firebase_admin import firestore
> cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
> firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
> ```

5. open your python IDE and paste the code.
6. save your python script in the same folder as the private key file
7. You cannot just use it yet, you need to install the python firebase admin library

> pip install firebase-admin

or visit https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/#files

8. the installation is successful, then you will have access to your database from python.
   add the ff. code

> ```
> db = firestore.client()
> ref_document = db.collection('new collection').document('new document')
> ref_document .set({
> "Name": "kojo",
> "age": 19
> })
> ```

9. Now run your code and refresh your firestore database

Answer (score 0):

### Step-1 :

#### Create a `script.py` file and Copy & Paste the following code in that file

```
from firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore, credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
ref_document = db.collection('new collection').document('new document')
ref_document .set({
"Name": "kojo",
"age": 19
})
```

### Step-2 : Install `firebase-admin` by running following command

`pip install firebase-admin`

### Step-3 : Download the service-account json file from Firebase

### Step-4 : Run the `script.py` file by running following command

`python script.py`

### Step-5 : Modify the `script.py` file as per your requirement